# How to rescan scsi bus devices?

Tags: linux, opensuse

How can I rescan a scsi bus for new devices under OpenSUSE?

I think it contains something like this:

```
echo "- - -" > scan
```

Comment: Did you google the subject line of your question first? If you did you need to say so and explain why you couldn't find the answer. If you hover over a downvote arrow it shows "does not show any research effort" as a primary reason to downvote a question!

Comment: On the other hand, I was searching this site for the same question, as I thought here would likely have the best information, being community-voted and all.  Why not be the canonical answer for this question on the Internet?  (Note: the accepted answer below worked in Debian too: my older installation of Debian had a different special file.  I don't think it's unreasonable to have such Googlable questions here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

<sub>(Where 0 is the scsi host bus you want to scan.)</sub>

Here is a [short article](http://misterd77.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-scan-scsi-bus-with-26-kernel.html).