# What are the commands to discover lun disks

Tags: linux, disk, iscsi

What are the commands to discover LUN disks in linux and esxi?

Comment: Which Linux you are using?

Comment: Have you asking about OpenISCSI on Linux? What have you done to setup initiator there?

Comment: I am using rhel os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for rescanning the scsi bus. If you search your distro + rescan scsi bus on the Internet you can find some guides on how to do that

Redhat based systems

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/rescan-scsi-bus.html
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/index.html#scanning-storage-interconnects

Debian/Ubuntu

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-rescan-a-scsi-bus-without-rebooting/

VmWare ESX

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003988

Also found another question/answer on SE

[How to rescan scsi bus devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17585/how-to-rescan-scsi-bus-devices)